# Where does Ubuntu Software Center install mscorefonts on Xubuntu? Where does it install anything?

Tags: installation, software-center, xubuntu, fonts

I have installed mscorefonts from Ubuntu Software Center. But I can't find them neither:

in `/etc/fonts/` nor

in `/usr/local/` nor

in `/usr/local/share/fonts/`.

Also I can't find any info about installed fonts in the `Installed` of Ubuntu Software Center. No any changes were made in `/etc/fonts/fonts.conf`.

Where does Ubuntu Software Center install fonts?

Why they are not present in `Installed` of Ubuntu Software Center?

How may I find out where does Ubuntu Software Center install something on my computer?

Comment: They might not be listed under installed software because they are listed as a utility/library package (which users normally wouldn't know or care about) rather than an application package.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a more advanced package manager frontend like synaptic to get a list of files a certain package has installed. Simply open synaptic, find the package you are interested in, right click and select Properties (I think - I'm using the German localisation). The window that opens should have a tab labelled 'Installed files'.

If you aren't afraid of the command line, there's a tool called apt-file that shows files in packages, even if they aren't installed.

Comment: You can also look at the file list via http://packages.ubuntu.com

Answer (score 1):

So far I found them in

`/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/`